# error when download using code igniter (pdf download became .file)

Tags: codeigniter, download

im trying to learn,

[here the file when im downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa5Ow.png)

here the script im using
controller

```html
function get_file(){
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $get_db=$this->m_dpks->get_file_byid($id);
        $q=$get_db->row_array();
        $file=$q['file_data'];
        $path='./assets/dpks/'.$file;
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        $name = $file;
        force_download($name, $data);
    }
```

here the view

```html
<?php
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_dpks;");
                      $no=1;
                      foreach ($query->result() as $row):
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $no++;?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->file_judul;?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->file_deskripsi;?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->file_oleh;?></td>
                      <td style="text-align:right;"><a href="<?php echo site_url('download/get_file/'.$row->file_id);?>" class="btn btn-info">Download</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php endforeach;?>
```

appreciate for help,

Comment: Is `$file=$q['file_data'];` the right path of your files? Try to print $file and $data to check if it's right. And don't write:`$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_dpks;");` in views, put it in controllers, codeigniter is core by MVC

Comment: yes its working but only to 1 file pdf,,but when im download other pdf, the rest became .file

Comment: I tested with your code. The download function works fine. Check again if something's wrong with your `$file` you got from database.

Comment: thank you so much im changing my query a bit and it work '<?php
     $no=0;
       foreach ($data->result_array() as $i) :
          $no++;
                       $id=$i['file_id'];
                       $judul=$i['file_judul'];
                       $deskripsi=$i['file_deskripsi'];
                       $oleh=$i['file_oleh'];
                       $tanggal=$i['tanggal'];
                       $download=$i['file_download'];
                       $file=$i['file_pks'];
                    ?>'

Comment: You're welcome :))). And you should update post's solution for other people if it can help